# Display color name in paletteColorPicker

Tags: jquery

I am using paletteColorPicker. Whenever hover the color it displays 1,2,3.Instead of 1,2,3 i want to display the color name of that color .
Javascript Code:

```
$('#colorPalette').paletteColorPicker({
  colors: [
    @foreach($colors as $color)
     {"{{ $color->id }}" : "{{ $color->code }}"},
     @endforeach
     ],
  position: 'upside',
});
```

Comment: by color name do you mean color code ??

Comment: try     **{"{{ $color->code  }}" : "{{ $color->id}}"},**